# Comparing dates in Azure Data factory expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This expression is evaluating false when I am running this today in my IF-Condition Activity

```
@equals(
activity('Pick the 4th working day').output.firstRow,
formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM-dd-yyyy'))
```

But, I am getting the value of Pick the 4th working day as

```
Output
{
    "firstRow": {
        "4thWorkingDay": "03-04-2021"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In you case, the output of this expression `activity('Pick the 4th working day').output.firstRow` is Object type, but `formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM-dd-yyyy')`'s result is String type. This is why they aren't equal.

```
{
        "4thWorkingDay": "03-04-2021"
        ........
}
```

Solution:
Use the following expression:

```
@equals(
activity('Pick the 4th working day').output.firstRow['4thWorkingDay'],
formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM-dd-yyyy'))
```

My test:

[image]

[image]

[image]